# Error update because of virtualbox

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, virtualbox, update-manager

so I wanted to install a dock bar called "docky". It, didn't work because I had to do the command `sudo apt-get update` but I get this output:

```
Hit:2 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:4 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease   
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease    
Hit:6 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 19.04 InRelease
Get:8 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian disco InRelease [4.428 B]
Err:8 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian disco InRelease
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
Err:9 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 19.04 Release
 404  Not Found [IP: 92.122.252.21 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian disco InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian disco InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 19.04 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't know how to fix this. Did anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the key for the virtualbox ppa like this:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Source, and more info at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

If you don't want or need the virtualbox ppa on your system, you can remove it by opening "Software and Updates" and unchecking it on the "Other Software" tab.

Comment: I added the keys, but when I try sudo apt update, I still get the same error...